# Find the length of the longest subsequence containing a number of consecutive k 0s followed by a number of consecutive k 1s

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

Given an array of 0 and 1, find the length of the longest subsequence containing a number of consecutive k 0s followed by a number of consecutive k 1s.

Note: It is possible to have 0s immediately before your subsequence and 1s immediately after, but it cannot happen simultaneously, otherwise your subsequence is not the longest.

Find an algorithm of excellent complexity.

This is where I am so far.

```
int subsequence(int v[], int dim){
int i, k_0=0, k_1=0, count_0=0, count_1=0, prev=-1;
for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {

    if (v[i] == 0 && prev == 1) {
        count_0 = 0;
        count_1 = 0;
        k_0 = k_1 = (k_0 < k_1) ? k_0 : k_1;
    }

    if (v[i] == 0) {
        count_0 += 1;
    }

    if (v[i] == 1) {
        count_1 += 1;
    }

    k_0 = (count_0 > k_0) ? count_0: k_0;
    k_1 = (count_1 > k_1) ? count_1: k_1;
    prev = v[i];
}
return (k_0 < k_1) ? k_0 : k_1;
```

}

```
Complexity O(n)
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem ?

Comment: In the assignment there is written about strings bur your code deals nothing with strings.:)

Comment: Changed the word "string" with "array" and "substring" with "subsequence".

Comment: @vlad, a string is an array.

Comment: @RichardBarker Strings are not integer arrays.

Comment: @Vlad chars are integers.

Comment: @RichardBarker This has nothing common with strings.

Comment: But it does. Strings are char arrays, chars are integers, therefore a string can be treated as an integer array. I'm not saying it's wise to do so, I'm just pointing out your initial comment was incorrect. Maybe I want to do math on a letter.

Comment: @RichardBarker No a string may not be considered as an integer array. You are entirely wrong.

Comment: I'm not wrong but I guess I can't argue with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to declare and define the function correctly with a more clear algorithm implementation.

The first parameter shall have the qualifier `const` and the second parameter shall have the type `size_t`. And the function return type also shall be `size_t`.

Within the function you should at first find the first element that is equal to 0 and only after that process the rest part of the array.

I would write the function the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t longest_subsequence( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    const int value1 = 0;
    const int value2 = 1;

    size_t longest = 0;

    size_t i = 0;
    while ( i < n && a[i] != value1 ) i++;

    while ( i < n )
    {

        size_t n1 = i;

        while ( i < n && a[i] == value1 ) i++;

        size_t n2 = i;

        while ( i < n && a[i] == value2 ) i++;

        n1 = n2 - n1;
        n2 = i - n2;

        n1 = n2 < n1 ? n2 : n1;

        if ( longest < 2 * n1 ) longest = 2 * n1;
    }

    return longest;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    printf( "%zu\n", longest_subsequence( a, N ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
6
```

Indeed the longest sub-sequence of the array is

```
{ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or the calculated value can look like

```
if ( longest < n1 ) longest = n1;
```

Principally it is unimportant how it can be calculated.

Comment: What's the time complexity of your algorithm ?

Comment: @ElDon90 It is O( n ). You can add a check whether the tail of the array is less than the already found sub-sequence.